# Is there a npm command to know where a particular node module is located

Tags: node.js, http, npm

I have been searching in every `node_modules` in my project but I cannot find where `http` module is located.

I'm using Windows and cannot find it in this path either `C:\Users\userx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

Is there a way or a command in npm to know where a particular module is located given the current path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case [`http` is built-in](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) so it's not part of `node_modules/`.

If it was a non-core library that you'd installed you'd find it somewhere in there, though it could be a sub-dependency so you may have to dig a little.

To see everything in your project, including dependencies:

```
npm list
```

That structure strongly mirrors how it's organised in the various subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm list to see the installed libraries for your current location or npm list -g to see where global libraries are installed.

Answer (score 1):

1) As @tadman said, `http` - a built-in module.

2) To search for locations not built-in module try to use the function [require.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve). For example:

```
console.log( require.resolve('express') );
```